# Is there a way to generate an execution plan for a stored procedure before executing it?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

We have a very large (many millions of rows) table that contains some (few million) rows with invalid values in particular columns.

A stored procedure exists to correct the invalid records but it takes a really long time to run the first time. It is significantly faster after that, as you would expect once the procedure has been compiled and the plan generated and cached. Unfortunately the procedure will probably only be executed once so we don't get the benefit of any optimization the server does during the first execution.

Is there some way to tell SQL Server to compile/generate/estimate an execution plan for a stored procedure before running the procedure?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191194.aspx

Comment: I would think that the reason for fast execution the second time is because the data has been retrieved from disc and is already in memory in the cache. Nothing to do with generating the execution plan.

Comment: In 2008 ThomasStringer's suggestion would work but in 2012 it won't cache the plan generated that way. @Wile I don't see how generating the plan in advance would help anyway even if it actually does take significant time to compile. It would still be the same total time just split into two separate operations (rather than having SQL Server automatically compile the plan then execute it immediately afterwards as one operation)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson I leapt straight to the assumption that the plan was cached and didn't think about the data. Thanks for reminding me that it might not be what I assumed.

Comment: @MartinSmith are you saying the estimated execution plan from the GUI is cached in 2008? I knew there would be overhead in generating the initial plan but hoped the combined time would be less than running the procedure "cold". I guess it makes sense that SQL Server probably does the estimation before the first run and replaces it with the actual plan afterwards.

Comment: @WileCau - Yes it is cached. Though if you generate the plan from SSMS it still may never be used by your application anyway as various settings need to consistent across both connections for plans to be shared. The execution plan tells you what the `CompileTime` is. What does it say in your case?

Comment: @MartinSmith Sorry for delay, I was running it on test system to get the CompileTime. I did FREEPROCCACHE DROPCLEANBUFFERS then ran the procedure and it took 2m42s total (much smaller data set than real life). There are 2 CompileTime values 1511 and 2342, which I think are ms so it's about 4s total for the compile. Looks like I'm barking up the wrong tree?